# CSS3 можно ли использовать в ключевых элементах сайта?

Tags: css3, веб-программирование, вёрстка, css

Насколько я знаю, СSS3 появилась относительно недавно, и соответсвенно, старые версии браузеров её не поддерживают. Подскажите, пожалуйста, допустимо ли делать ключевые элементы сайта с использованием СSS3 (ключевые в том смысле, что я буду использовать transform для элементов навигации, и если в старом браузере этот стиль не сработает, то страничка будет выглядить, не как страничка, а как куча рандомно разбросаных кнопок, пользоваться ей будет невозможно). Поэтому очень интересно узнать мнение специалистов о том, сколько сейчас людей используют старые браузеры, и насколько критично использование CSS3... Есть ли какие-то проф. рекомендации?

Comment: ага, делать эффекты так, чтобы с их отсутствием не получалась каша, использовать modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

transform поддерживается всеми современными браузерами, включая IE9+, которым на данный момент пользуются примерно 1.6% пользователей Рунета. С остальными свойствами ситуация примерно похожая. Поэтому вам решать, нужно ли использовать данные свойства на своем сайте или нет.